# Bounty reason isn't showing up

Tags: bug, bounty

A couple days ago, I started a bounty on [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/13225/627), selecting the reason "Authoritative reference needed". I didn't add any supplementary text; I felt that the default wording said enough. When I checked on it today, I saw the following:

[image]

Now, if I'm not mistaken, the words "Authoritative reference needed" (or something similar) should appear in the tan box below that sentence. This works correctly for [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/113637/627) - bountied just today:

[image]

This seems like a bit of a bug to me.

I'm using Google Chrome on Windows 10. Microsoft Edge shows the same problem.

Comment: Yay, I am useful!

Comment: It's got to be that hard-science notice.  I think post notices interact badly with other notices, and even though it's gone now, there's probably some snarly code there that rarely gets exercised.  You're only two days in, so (speaking as a moderator) I wouldn't have a problem with you canceling and restarting it, given that there's clearly a bug here.  (But you might want to ask Shog if he thinks that would actually work first.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Tempted though I am to science it out, I think I'm okay with not restarting it this time around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like the bounty reason notice got removed the same instant that you removed the hard science notice, probably because both are technically notices on the question. That's plainly visible in the [revision history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/13225/revisions) if you look at the exact timestamps.

Another UI quirk? But yes, I'd definitely call this **unexpected behavior** at the very least.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I thought the "notice removed" was a different bug - just the removal of the hard science notice recorded twice. But that makes a lot of sense.